what the point of ": &&" command
I use ninja build system and i got some errors in the build process.
Ninja prints the command that raised the error and it seems that every commands look like this:
: && /usr/bin/g++ -Wno-attributes -pthread -g3 -ggdb3 ...
What the point of starting the command with : && ? I understand that it lokks like if true then cmd but I don't get the point.

: && /usr/bin/g++ ...  essentially means "do nothing, and if that succeeds (which it always will), then execute the g++ command".

: means no-op (no operation)

If you added : && to the ninja file, why did you add it then? Ask the author of the ninja file that you are using. Was the ninja file generated by cmake? please specify the origin or content of the build.ninja file that you are using, i.e. please create an [MCVE]

@ReeceHarris not quite, side-effects still happen

@jhnc Really i remember reading that : essentially means no operation is just used as a placeholder

@ReeceHarris "This utility shall only expand command arguments. It is used when a command is needed, as in the then condition of an if command, but nothing is to be done by the command." Consider : a=$(touch file1) >file2 (I'm thinking of the general case; you're right that if there is notthing else, then : does nothing)

One possibility is that this Bash script is being generated by some program, and there are some conditions under which the : would have been a real command instead. It may be simpler for that program to always emit COMMAND && ... at this point in its output, with the command being : when there's nothing to do there, than for the program to emit the COMMAND && part only when needed. (In other words, this may just be a weird artifact of the logic that happened to generate the command.)
Edited to add: Another possibility — also specific to generated code — is that the generating program is building a dynamic list of commands that need to be run in the form COMMAND1 && COMMAND2 && COMMAND3. It can be convenient, in that case, for it to start with : and then add each command by appending && COMMAND, rather than having to keep track of whether a given command is the first.
